# Re-positioning tab view to bottom in nativescript angular

Tags: angularjs, tabs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Can any one explain me how can change the position of native script tabs to bottom for nativescript with angular framework implementation

```
<TabView **property here to be used to make align at bottom**>
....
....
</TabView>
```

Answer (score 2):

On iOS tabs appear in the bottom of the view, as this is the standard, however in Android a flag must be set:

`<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom"  >`

This is taken from [the TabView documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/tab-view#tabs-position) on the NativeScript website. I also happened to be in a position to test this immediately on an Android emulator and can confirm it is working (at the time of writing).